# Eclipse egit push to two remote repositories

Tags: eclipse, egit

Is it possible to add two different remotes such as github and sourceforge in Eclipse egit? 
If it possible how push to remote repositories are performed? And can I select the repositories to push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

I assume that you have two different repositories in the github and sourceforge with same project in both and you would like to update the github and sourceforge with the same commits then it is possible and you have to configure the Push to Upstream

Please check the following:

Right Click on Team -> Remotes -> Configure Push to Upstream

Add Push URI (github and sourceforge in your case)

Save your configuration.

[image: Configure Push to Upstream]

I hope this works. Please let me know if this what you wanted or re-phrase your question with additional information.

Thank you